# How can I send an ASP.NET table as body of outlook message?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook

I have an asp.net (VB) table with information so I have to send the table at the full webpage as an email but it should be like if I press a button outlook should be open with the mail body as my html table or full html page. Please help me on this

PS: please help with VB code

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using System.Net.* namespace classes or any other third-party components designed for the server side execution. In case if you deal with an Exchange account you may find EWS helpful. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass mail body in mailto action. Like **mailto:abc@ymail.com?body=SampleContent**.

Also

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var toAddress = "abc@ymail.com";
        $("#lnkMail").attr("href", "mailto:" + toAddress + "?body=" + encodeURIComponent($("#tbl").html()));
    });
```

But if content is large, it may not work.